# Session data from textbox inputed by user

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have this project where I want to transfer data from `textbox1` with session "sam" on the `about.aspx` on its `label`. The problem is that when I input a number, it is not shown on `label`. My problem is that I type something on the "Αριθμός Επιβατών:" `textbox` (a number for example) and after that I click submit I need to get the number on the about page next to "Ari8mos epivatwn :"

Defaultaspxcs.txt:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication4
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string txt = TextBox1.Text;
            Session["sam"] = txt;
        }
    }
}
```

Aboutaspxcs.txt:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication4
{
    public partial class About : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = (string)Session["sam"];
        }
    }
}
```

Aboutaspx.txt:

```
<%@ Page Title="About Us" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master"  AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="About.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication4.About" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<p>
    Ari8mos epivatwn :
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</p>
</asp:Content>
```

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4ftlddfhqo8n99p/gm-TNvol0S

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the content for the Label is being written twice, and not in the order your expect.

Start by familiarizing yourself with the [asp.net page life-cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

You will notice that `PageLoad` is called long before `Render`.

So, the page loads like this:

1. `PageLoad` Label text set to some number from your code
2. A bunch of other stuff
3. `Render` sets the Label text to "Label" instead, since that is what you have defined in your chtml.

Review this part of your code:

```
...
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
...
```

Try this instead:

```
...
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
...
```

Comment: On the about page i still do not get the number that i input on the textbox.

Comment: @user2052363 What does it show instead? Also, when you debug, is your Page_Load method being hit?

Comment: The debug is clear. And it shows nothing, like i do not have the session.